# Encoding with Unicode - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, encoding

I am creating a messaging application for iOS and am having trouble encoding the user-inputted data. I have done a lot of research on the subject but I am not able to encode all Unicode characters. I have a tried doing this is many different ways, but here is the method I am currently using:

```
- (NSString *)encodeString:(NSString *)string {

     NSData *dataenc = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
     NSString *encodevalue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataenc encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

     return encodevalue;  

}
```

This seems to work with emojis but some other characters and line breaks are not encoded properly.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why are you using `NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding` to build the `NSData`? Why not use `NSUTF8StringEncoding`?

Comment: @Rob I tried that and it doesn't work either. Also, I want to note that I am using AFNetworking, which encodes the parameters with UTF8 by default. For some reason, it doesn't seem to encode properly in my case. I get an internal server error when sending emojis so my hunch is that it might have something to do with the configuration on the back-end. Android version does encode successfully though, which is the confusing part.

Comment: What is your goal here? What type of encoding are you actually try to use? What do you do with the encoded string returned from this `encodeString:` method?

Comment: @rmaddy Frankly, I am new to encoding, but I have recently read a lot about this topic with no avail. I want all Unicode characters to be encoded properly. The encoded string would be sent to the server and stored in the remote database. We are developing for Android as well and I have had no problems decoding the JSON response when the POST request is encoded on Android. The Android developer is using the StringUtils class to encode the user-inputted text.

Comment: @user2589649 Perhaps show us the Android code? Or, send an emoji via Android and show us the binary representation of the request?

Comment: You shouldn't need any encoding. Simply add your `NSString` as-is to your data. Build the JSON using `NSJSONSerialization`, and send the JSON to your server.

Comment: @sublimepremise: Do you get any solution?I am also stuck with same issue.